# Showing textbox.text in alert messege

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this project where people are allowed to upload small projects of their own, this includes a title, description, category and url.

I have the following alert message:

```
 Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "success", "alert('Succesfully added');", True)
```

This is the part where they can insert a category in to the database. 
But is it possible to have something like this:

```
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "thanks", "alert(//NOTE THIS'TextBoxCategory.Text// is succesfully added');")
```

So it displays the value of the text box and would say : `"Website" is succesfully added`

I have tried it like this and with .value behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType,"Message", "<script>alert('"+TextBoxCategory.text+'" is successfully added.')</script>", false);
return;
```

Comment: The idea of `Website` has been added is that `website` is the value of TextBoxCategory. So `website` is what ever the user filled in

Comment: ok.Place it like this. ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Message", "<script>alert('"+TextBoxCategory.Text+"' is successfully added.')</script>", false);
return;

Comment: do i have to declare `this` ? cuz its throwing me a error, did you notice i script in vb.net right

Comment: is there is no textbox named TextBoxCategory.Since u have mentioned textbox as TextBoxCategory.so I have placed that.Place the name of textbox which has that value.

Comment: Well there def is. But when I try to use your code :
cs.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Message", "<script>alert('"+TextBoxCategory.Text+"' is successfully added.')</script>", false); return;

it gives an error on : `(this,` (not decalred) and on `(string)` ( string is a class and cannot be used as a expression)

Comment: try replacing Me.GetType() instead of this.

Comment: and then ad "+TextBoxCategory.Text+"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29291/discussion-between-mahaswetha-and-diederikeen)

Comment: let me rewrite @MahaSwetha 's code in VB: `cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "thanks", "alert('""" + TextBoxCategory.Text + """ is successfully added.');", True)` This will show the exact string as you want with the double-quotes around the text value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Dim msg As String
 msg = String.Format("<script>alert('{0}')</script>", TextBoxCategory.Text)
 cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "thanks", msg)
```